# JVM : What is the great thing about "stack" that it used for JVM as a preferred choice to store locals?

Tags: java, jvm, stack, queue

Instead of Stack, Queue can also be used for it. Why JVM uses "Stack" for local variables and calls to methods for memory management? I already google my question but don't get exactly answer about it.

Comment: Because a stack is LIFO and a queue is FIFO. What's the "great thing" about a queue? Why prefer queue over stack?

Comment: thanks @VinceEmigh That i know,I want to know what makes LIFO is better choice rather than FIFO in JVM?

Comment: What is the alternative for the model where you call a method from another ?

Comment: Think about washing dishes. It is easier as a stack or a queue?

Comment: Why we compare it with only dishes example? If we compare it with square or rectangle "Blocks" than updating any block will ll be much easier in Queue than Stack. let me correct if i'm guessing wrong.

Comment: Obviously you have never washed dishes. If the pile is 100. Would you pick the first at the bottom risking breaking the rest or pick the last? It is a lot less effort. and less error prone to pick the last at the top

Comment: @JaiminPatel "*Stacks entered the computer science literature in 1946 ... as a means of calling and returning from subroutines*" - You should really be asking yourself why you expect/prefer a queue rather than a stack. Read some bytecode, it'll "click" (you'll realize why it's used/prefer). This question is something you can answer yourself simply by looking into it's usage, then attempting to replace it with a different collection type.

Comment: Please expand your question and explain how you believe a Queue would work for tracking methods calls and their local variables.

Answer (score 7):

As @Vince mentioned in the comment, Stack is Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) and a Queue is First-In-First-Out (FIFO) list.

When methods are called, they usually have a sequence like so,

- method m1 calls method m2
- method m2 calls method m3
- method m3 calls method m4
- ...

When method m4 returns, the execution returns to method m3.

When method m3 returns, the execution returns to method m2, and so on.

Finally method m1 finishes its execution.

Notice that method m1 was the first to get called, but the last to finish its execution. Thus storing method calls on a stack facilitates memory management (as stack is LIFO).

Local variables are declared and defined in methods, and are hence also stored on stack.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, when execution reaches a `}` character, any local variables that were declared since the matching `{` character go out of scope, and the memory that was used for them (references or primitive variables, not objects) can be reused.  But the matching `{` character is the `{` that was encountered most recently, that has not yet been matched by a `}` character.

Therefore, variables go out of scope on a "most recently created" basis.  Those most recently declared will be the ones that disappear first.  Those that were declared earliest will be the last ones that disappear.

You couldn't do this with a queue.  Local variables need to be in a "last in first out" structure such as a stack.

Comment: thanks for valuable information... @Dawood ibn Kareem

Answer (score 2):

It’s a fundamental, inevitable property of a thread’s code flow, that the last entered method will be the first to return from. Even in the exceptional case, where more than one method may be left, it will be the *last n* methods. Therefore, a LIFO data structure is the *only* choice, not just the “better” one.

That said, this kind of Stack is a *logical* concept, not an implementation requirement. The [specification states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2):

> Each Java Virtual Machine thread has a private *Java Virtual Machine stack*, created at the same time as the thread. A Java Virtual Machine stack stores frames ([§2.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6)). A Java Virtual Machine stack is analogous to the stack of a conventional language such as C: it holds local variables and partial results, and plays a part in method invocation and return. Because the Java Virtual Machine stack is never manipulated directly except to push and pop frames, frames may be heap allocated. The memory for a Java Virtual Machine stack does not need to be contiguous.

The last two sentences hint at the JVM’s freedom of how to implement that Stack. In fact, something like a linked list of heap allocated stack frames would be possible. However, providing efficient “push” and “pop” operations, to add and remove frames at the same end, is crucial.

In case the term [Stack Frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) needs clarifications:

> A *frame* is used to store data and partial results, as well as to perform dynamic linking, return values for methods, and dispatch exceptions.
>
> A new frame is created each time a method is invoked. A frame is destroyed when its method invocation completes, whether that completion is normal or abrupt (it throws an uncaught exception). Frames are allocated from the Java Virtual Machine stack ([§2.5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2)) of the thread creating the frame.

This relationship, i.e. the requirement to create and push a new frame on every method invocation and to pop and destroy it upon method completion, dictates how the Java Virtual Machine stack has to work.

Answer (score 1):

This question has nothing to do with Java or JVM. Or rather, it is not *specific* to JVM, but is questioning the concept of a [**Call Stack**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), as implemented by pretty much all programming languages.

If you study how method calls work, in particular how the return from a method call is handled, and how local variables are stored *with* the call return information, you'd quickly realize that a call-queue would make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: What a wonderful answer, Idk the smart who upvotes an answer saying *go study and search*